# Power BI Data Flows Access to the resource is forbidden error

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-lake

I have created a new workspace in Power BI that has dataflows which are backed by Azure Data Lake Gen2 storage.  I have created several of these and can use them without issue in Power BI Desktop.  I have given another person permission (currently they have Admin role) to the Workspace and I have even given them permission (again Owner at this point) to the Gen2 Data Lake.  But whenever that person tries to use Power BI to pull in that Data Flow they get the following error message

"Expression.Error: Access to the resource is forbidden"

Can somebody please tell me what permissions are needed to allow people to read information from the data flows that are backed by Gen2 Data Lake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you managed to fix this, but I came across the same issue and I found a trace of a solution on Power BI Community Website: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Read-access-to-a-Dataflow-as-a-data-source-by-a-non-owner-of-the/m-p/743544/highlight/true#M72483

It seems that any other user that wants read access on a Dataflow, if the Dataflow data is physically saved in a dedicated ADLS Gen2 Storage Account, that user will also need to be granted permissions on every folder and file there is in there...

Thanks